# Ajax is not working in chrome of new mobiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I have made a modal form in which I have made dependent dropdown lists. I am fetching the lists with ajax call. Everything is working in Every browser of desktop and also it's working well in phone's browser. The problem is that it's working on some mobile chrome while doesn't work on other phone's mobile chrome. specially which are new in the market.

I want to know what should I do to make ajax run in all the mobile chromes of every mobile.

I have tried it by changing POST to GET and also tried to change Http to Https for the security purpose.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    var btn = $("btn2").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'data.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: 'btn=' + btn
    }).done(function(category) {
      console.log(category);
      category = JSON.parse(category);
      category.forEach(function(category) {
        $("#category2").append('<option id="' + category.cat_id + '" value="' + category.cat_id + '">' + category.cat_name + '</option>')
      })
    })
  })
})
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#category2").change(function() {
    var cat = $("#category2").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'data.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: 'cat=' + cat
    }).done(function(area) {
      console.log(area);
      area = JSON.parse(area);
      area.forEach(function(area) {
        $("#location").append('<option id="' + area.area_id + '" value="' + area.area_id + '">' + area.area_name + '</option>')
      })
    })
  })
})
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#location").change(function() {
    var loc = $("#location").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'data.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: 'loc=' + loc
    }).done(function(doctor) {
      console.log(doctor);
      doctor = JSON.parse(doctor);
      $('#doctor').empty();
      doctor.forEach(function(doctor) {
        $("#doctor").append('<option id="' + doctor.doc_id + '" value="' + doctor.doc_id + '">' + doctor.doc_name + '</option>')
      })
    })
  })
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#date2').datetimepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  })
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error/warning? It does nothing? However, I would suggest to directly use the `XMLHttpRequest()` API to avoid possible issues with jQuery

Comment: Please use `$(document).ready(function()` only once. There you'll have to put your eventHandlers in.

Comment: I mean when I click on select it just shows a popup and does not get any data from the database. The problem is in chrome of new phones only

Comment: Does it not work at all on those new devices, or does it work intermittently? If it's the latter it sounds like a connection issue, not a code/device one

Comment: Not to all but few and not even working intermittently. If it's not working its completely not working in some devices

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#btn2").click(function(){

        var btn= $("btn2").val();

           $.ajax({

                     url: 'data.php',
                     method: 'POST',
                     ContentType:'application/json',
                     data : 'btn='+ btn

           }).done(function(category){

                     console.log(category); 

                     category = JSON.parse(category);

                     category.forEach(function(category){

                         $("#category2").append('<option id="'+category.cat_id+'" value="'+category.cat_id+'">' +category.cat_name+ '</option>')

                     })

           })



       })

       $("#category2").change(function(){

        var cat= $("#category2").val();

           $.ajax({

                     url: 'data.php',
                     method: 'POST',
                     ContentType:'application/json',
                     data : 'cat='+ cat

           }).done(function(area){

                     console.log(area); 

                     area = JSON.parse(area);

                     area.forEach(function(area){

                         $("#location").append('<option id="'+area.area_id+'" value="'+area.area_id+'">' +area.area_name+ '</option>')

                     })

           })



       })


       $("#location").change(function(){

        var loc= $("#location").val();

           $.ajax({

                     url: 'data.php',
                     method: 'POST',
                     ContentType:'application/json',
                     data : 'loc='+ loc

           }).done(function(doctor){

                     console.log(doctor); 

                     doctor = JSON.parse(doctor);

                     $('#doctor').empty();

                     doctor.forEach(function(doctor){

                         $("#doctor").append('<option id="'+doctor.doc_id+'" value="'+doctor.doc_id+'">' +doctor.doc_name+ '</option>')

                     })

           })



       })


     $('#date2').datetimepicker({
                minDate:new Date(),
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [1,2,3,4,5]
            })

   })
```